# Aligning centred text with more text on the right of same line

Tags: alignment, center

I need to align the text on the right on the same line as the centred text. Looking for a straightforward answer and as short as possible of a solution. I've attached an image showing the right aligned text that should be on the same line as above:

[image]

Thanks!

```
\begin{description}
\centering
    \item[Gain Margin:] \(\frac{1}{0.165} = 6.06\)                  
    \item[Phase Margin:] 83\textdegree  \begin{flushright}{...below -180\textdegree}\end{flushright}     
\end{description}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \textbf{Gain Margin:} \(\frac{1}{0.165} = 6.06\)
                      
    \hfill\textbf{Phase Margin:} 83\textdegree \hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{...below -180\textdegree}     
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz this works perfectly.

Comment: @Fish4November You're welcome!